# cannot open No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to store the output of total count to a variable and then print the variable.

```
for i in `cat /home/retailer.sh`;do file = "$(grep $i /home/DD.inventory.loaded_master_list.txt|sort -u|wc -l)";echo $file;done
```

`/home/retailer.sh`
HAG
GAT

```
/home/DD.inventory.loaded_master_list.txt
```

/dailydata_hershey/prd/work/all/2109/delivery/POSDATA_FINAL.GAT.20200201.dat
/dailydata_hershey/prd/work/all/2109/delivery/POSDATA_FINAL.HAG.20200201.dat

Below error i get
`=:   cannot open = (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file = "$(...)"` - you have to use `file="$(...)"` (no spaces).

Otherwise it will be interpreted as a command.  (e.g. `file` with an argument of `=`)

For future reference, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great resource for catching these kinds of things.  Just copy-paste your script into the box and it will tell you all of the errors, how to fix them, and a handful of other warnings about potential bugs.